# compare #defines in two C files using a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have 2 files with content like

```
Fil1.c
#define V1 2
...
int Var[V1] ;
******************************
Fil2.c
#define V2 3
...
int Var[V2];
```

I need to compare V1 with V2 in a batch file, and
throw an error if they don't match.
Using *Findstr* would give multiple line matches in single file
and would not extract numerical value from entire line of data. 
Any ideas on how to do that in an efficient manner without calling external program to do that?
Thanks
sedy

Comment: using `sed` and `diff` is the easiest way. But you didn't specify what is your environment and what you mean by "external program"

Comment: You could also use `fc` for the comparison (`ErrorLevel` is `0` for equality and `1` otherwise); `comp` would work as well, but requires user interaction.

Comment: Please precise your post: you are only interested in the line starting with `#define`, right? is that keyword unique in each file? or is it always in the second line? are you interested in the variable names `V1`/`V2`, or only in their respective values `2`/`3`?

Comment: @aschipfl Yes, I am only interested in lines with #define. (there might be multiple occurrences of V1/V2 but those should be ignored). The keywords can be at different line numbers and I want to compare their values. And By external program, I mean Matlab etc should not be called upon.Note that V1/V2 can be different names in those 2 files, so just comparing 2 lines literally would be wrong .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off

rem Get value of *first* #define in both Fil1.c and Fil2.c
for /F "tokens=3" %%a in ('findstr "^#define" Fil1.c') do set "Fil1=%%a" & goto continue1
:continue1
for /F "tokens=3" %%a in ('findstr "^#define" Fil2.c') do set "Fil2=%%a" & goto continue2
:continue2

if "%Fil1%" neq "%Fil2%" (
   echo They don't match"
)
```

If you want to compare *precisely* `V1` in Fil1.c and `V2` in Fil2.c:

```
@echo off

for /F "tokens=3" %%a in ('findstr /B /C:"#define V1" Fil1.c') do set "Fil1=%%a" & goto continue1
:continue1
for /F "tokens=3" %%a in ('findstr /B /C:"#define V2" Fil2.c') do set "Fil2=%%a" & goto continue2
:continue2

if "%Fil1%" neq "%Fil2%" (
   echo They don't match"
)
```

Comment: Thanks ,using tokens was  the key.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off

set "file1=c:\file1.c"
set "file2=c:\file.c"

fc "%file1%" "%file2%" && (
  echo files are the same
  color
) || (
  echo files are different
)
```