# extracting specified match from find/findstr results

Tags: batch-file

so this is related to 
[compare #defines in two C files using a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32057673/compare-defines-in-two-c-files-using-a-batch-file)
but different:
System is Win 7(no Linux commands).
I have 2 files with content like

```
Fil1.c
#define V1 6
...
int Var[V1] ;
******************************
Fil2.c

ifdef USE_V1
#define V1 6
#else
#define V1 5
#endif
```

I need to compare V1 with V2 in a batch file, and throw an error if they don't match.
The solution

```
for /f "tokens=3" %%A in ('find "#define V1" "Fil1.c"') DO (
    set Var1=%%A)
for /f "tokens=3" %%A in ('find "#define V1" "Fil2.c") DO (
    set Var2=%%A)
if "%VAR1%" neq "%VAR2%" goto Error2
```

works well when *USE_V1* preprocessor is set to 0.However, when set to 1, *V1* in *File2.c* still reads value 5 ,as *findtsr* finds 2 occurrences of *#define* , and gets the last one.

Is there a way for findstr to read only 1st or second  occurrence of #define ( which I can specify based on GOTO, wherein I read USE_V1 defined in VS project xml and decide which findstr I need to execute, that which reads first occurence or that which reads second one.)

For example, I can try :

```
TYPE nul >%tmpPth%    
findstr /N /C:"#define V1" "Fil2.c" > %tmpPth%
```

writes following to tmp.txt

> 46:#define V1 6
>     49:#define V1 5

but then, I should be able to read token 3 using find/findstr either from first line or second line.
I have seen solutions on stack overflow ([[Batch file to output last line of findstr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21007472/batch-file-to-output-last-line-of-findstr)[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUOL3.jpg)) that read/print only last occurrence of 
search string but I need solution where I can probably choose which line out of the matched results I need to re-run the search for, and not just print but extract tokens out of the line result.

Update: I was able to do following:

```
set USE_V1="0"
for /f "delims= " %%A in ('findstr /C:"USE_V1" %VCProjPath%') DO (
 set USE_V1="1")
set Var3="0"

for /f "tokens=3" %%A in ('find "#define V1" "Fil1.c"') DO (
    set Var1=%%A)
if %USE_V1% equ "1" goto USE_V1_USED
for /f "tokens=3" %%A in ('find "#define V1" "Fil2.c"') DO (
    set Var2=%%A)
goto MOVEON
:USE_V1_USED

TYPE nul >%tmpPth1%
findstr /C:"#define V1" "Fil2.c" > %tmpPth1%
for /f "tokens=3 delims= " %%A in ('findstr /C:"#define V1" %tmpPth1%') Do (
  set Var2=%%A  
  if "%VAR2%" neq "%VAR3%" goto MOVEON  
  )  
:MOVEON
if "%VAR1%" neq "%VAR2%" goto Error0
```

The problem i face is that supposing *#define V1*  match in *File1.c* and *File2.c* and

> findstr /C:"#define V1" "Fil2.c" > %tmpPth1%

writes to tmp file as

```
#define NUMATTR1MEMS 6
#define NUMATTR1MEMS 5
```

which when read using

```
for /f "tokens=3 delims= " %%A in ('findstr /C:"#define V1" %tmpPth1%') Do (
      set Var2=%%A  
      if "%VAR2%" neq "%VAR3%" goto MOVEON  
      )
```

give op with *%VAR2%* from both files as

[image]
As seen, the second value corresponding to first line read from temp file has extra blank spaces ,so, even though values match numerically, the command to match these fails.

So, is there a way to redirect *findstr* op to text file without extra blanks at line endings?

Thanks
sedy

Comment: The [answer of your other similar post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32059003/5047996) already provides a way to get the first occurrence of a string (parsing the string with `for /F`, storing the needed token with `set` and leaving the `for` loop immediately with `goto`; omitting the `goto` continues iterating until the last occurrence is reached, so `set` overwrites each previous value). A simple `if` against `USE_V1` with the `goto` in its body would do the trick. The only remaining question is: how to get the value of `USE_V1`; is it an environvent variable?

Comment: @aschipfl  Hi aschipfl, I have updated my question based on your suggestion. also, **USE_V1** is preprocessor set in visual studio project settings.

Comment: Okay... I think the temporary file (in `%tmpPath1%`) in your new code snippet is not needed as you can directly parse the output of `findstr`; the variable `Var3` make no sense too (I guess it constitutes a constant used for comparisons against `0`); and I don't get where the trailing spaces come from (or is it possible that this is actually a tabulator character origined from file `Fil2.c`? you specified `"delim= "`, meaning spaces only, but the default was spaces _and_ tabs; perhaps you should remove the `delims` option...).

Answer (score 0):

Let us go through the quite huge amount of tasks step by step...

---

At first, let's concentrate on retrieving the definition of `USE_V1`. As far as I understand, you have a project definition file that contains `USE_V1`; if `USE_V1` is present in that file literally, it is considered as defined, otherwise not.
The following code snippet seeks `USE_V1` and sets `%VVALGLOB%` if found (I place a couple of `set` statements for initially setting up everything at one place for convenience):

```
@echo off

rem global project definitions
set FILEPROJ="\path\to\project\file"
set VNAMGLOB=USE_V1
set VVALGLOB=

rem seek %VNAMGLOB% in project file and set %VVALGLOB% if found
for /F %%A in ('findstr /L /I "%VNAMGLOB%" %FILEPROJ%') do (
  set VVALGLOB=1
)
```

---

The next thing is to extract the value of variable `V1` from `Fil1.c`. Here I assume that *always* the *first* occurrence of the `#define` directive is the one to regard:

```
rem definition of data of file 1
set FILE1="Fil1.c"
set VNAM1=V1
set VVAL1=

rem processing file 1, always take FIRST occurrence of "#define"
for /F "tokens=3" %%A in ('findstr /R /I /C:"^ *#define  *%VAR1%" %FILE1%') do (
  set /A "VVAL1=%%A"
  goto :CONT1
)
:CONT1
```

I used `set /A` rather than `set` here to treat the gathered value as a number.

---

Now let's extract the value of `V1` from `Fil2.c` conditionally: Here I check whether or not `%VVALGLOB%` is defined (remember it is when `USE_V1` has been defined); if it is, the *first* occurrence of the `#define` directive is taken; otherwise, the *last* one is checked:

```
rem definition of data of file 2
set FILE2="Fil2.c"
set VNAM2=V1
set VVAL2=

rem processing file 2, take FIRST OR LAST occurrence of "#define" conditionally
for /F "tokens=3" %%A in ('findstr /R /I /C:"^ *#define  *%VAR2%" %FILE2%') do (
  set /A "VVAL2=%%A"
  if defined VVALGLOB goto :CONT2
)
:CONT2
```

Alternatively, if only the *first* or *second* occurrence of `#define` is relevant, which is the case when there are more than two such directives, the `for /F` portion of the code must be replaced by the following lines:

```
rem processing file 2, take FIRST OR SECOND occurrence of "#define" conditionally
for /F "tokens=3" %%A in ('findstr /R /I /C:"^ *#define  *%VAR2%" %FILE2%') do (
  if defined VVAL2 (
    set "VVAL2=%%A"
    goto :CONT2
  )
  set /A "VVAL2=%%A"
  if defined VVALGLOB goto :CONT2
)
:CONT2
```

---

Having extracted the correct values from the two files, we need to compare them. For this, I assumed that they must not equal zero to be considered as valid. If one or both are zero, or if they are not equal, a message is thrown and the batch script is exited; otherwise, the batch script continues executing:

```
rem compare found values for equality in a NUMERICAL manner (both != 0)
if %VVAL1% neq 0 if %VVAL2% neq 0 if %VVAL1% equ %VVAL2% goto :MOVEON
echo They don't match! & exit /B

:MOVEON
rem ...
```

Since there are no double-quotes around all the values, a numerical comparison is done rather than a string comparison. Hence any trailing spaces do not matter.

---

**Notes:**
I added the `/I` switch to all `findstr` occurrences in order to do case-insensitive searches. However, if all the variable names like `V1` are case-sensitive, just remove it.
For searching the `#define` directive, I established a regular expression rather than a literal search string, telling `findstr` to allow leading spaces and more than one space between the keyword and the variable name.
As already mentioned in the above I treat variable (`V1`) values of zero as invalid to avoid trouble with values other than integers. For instance, if `V1` is a string `abc` in your file, the batch script reads `0`.